# Unable to deploy Multus CNI into my cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie to Kubernetes, and am facing some issues with the Multus plugin.
I am using CentOS-7 and minikube.

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.18.0
commit: ec61815d60f66a6e4f6353030a40b12362557caa-dirty

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:20:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I am trying to integrate the multus plugin with K8s. To do this, I obtained the source code for multus from:
https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni

Compiled it with ./hack/build-go.sh

Then I have been following the details in https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md.

However, the pod never gets created; it gets stuck in ContainerCreating forever.

I create the network-attachment-definitions with the following in a yml file and kubectl apply -f:

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: macvlan-conf
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "master": "ens33",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "192.168.152.0/24",
        "rangeStart": "192.168.152.200",
        "rangeEnd": "192.168.152.216",
        "routes": [
          { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "gateway": "192.168.152.1"
      }
    }'
```

This is the output of kubectl describe:

```
Name:         macvlan-conf
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
Kind:         NetworkAttachmentDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-03-16T17:07:38Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-03-16T17:07:38Z
  Resource Version:  102230
  UID:               8473cdbf-1906-48b8-b180-e6f49502254d
Spec:
  Config:  { "cniVersion": "0.3.0", "type": "macvlan", "master": "ens33", "mode": "bridge", "ipam": { "type": "host-local", "subnet": "192.168.152.0/24", "rangeStart": "192.168.152.200", "rangeEnd": "192.168.152.216", "routes": [ { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" } ], "gateway": "192.168.152.1" } }
Events:    <none>
```

Then I create the pod using the following yml and kubectl apply -f :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: samplepod1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: samplepod1
    command: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]
    image: alpine
```

The output of kubectl get pods is (samplepod1 is the relevant one):

```
NAME         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
samplepod    0/1     Terminating         0          54m
samplepod1   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          35s
```

kubectl describe pods gives me:

```
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:   Tue, 16 Mar 2021 13:15:08 -0400
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  samplepod1:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         alpine
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/ash
      -c
      trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-7vg94 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-7vg94:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-7vg94
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               64s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/samplepod1 to minikube
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  62s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "26bcf14c4ec6cf8b532233abeefd7f6d9b2493b62963692d6460215dbb86916d" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  59s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "e478b9559dc0837e2f1e1a78f1ca4f40b521a5176b9680ffefcaa4b485981a06" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  56s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "7749375a5a4598313bace4a83d14e146af73e686098f8d82ccf1700d49663a1b" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  53s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "0d5c368e0b953c7463937d7c8f659b8554a467187a9f28462a348a7b64534689" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  50s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "a93077c4f10db6c81d6ad23e353ebe024d32b5cbaf12e6618255c5286890ba34" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  47s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "cc760d4034006f563bea6a4173e7fe0ae10e8bebe24327c9b28798121c9ca5d3" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  44s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "df255fbcd396c7f3bca09bce56220285aef8f063016ebc71f78428deb7ee24fb" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  41s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "62e3b999cb14cb116a2245d383fc05f819d0786da4c0ee4a24ce64fb239a9851" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  39s                 kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "07464566ca12539d54e73c3bf1ac73faebed6634703250954a8329e948954faf" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
  Normal   SandboxChanged          29s (x12 over 61s)  kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  26s (x4 over 36s)   kubelet            (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "2c75fc7558d368e364a3c48793deb93dd77b6579b9a47eb8a82a7b4037ae344d" network for pod "samplepod1": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "samplepod1_default" network: [default/samplepod1:crio]: error adding container to network "crio": failed to set bridge addr: could not add IP address to "cni0": permission denied
```

In this case, I have not even used "annotations" in the spec for the pod.

Could someone help me debug this?

**Edited**:
I re-did the entire sequence. Point to note, is that I had to get a totally new and fresh RHEL8 VM installation because I'd destroyed the previous one totally.
Now the results is still a failure, but slightly different as below.

The steps followed were :

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
$ minikube start --driver=docker
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   24h   v1.20.2
$ git clone https://github.com/intel/multus-cni.git && cd multus-cni
$ cat ./images/multus-daemonset.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

At this point, its worth noting that there is nothing in the /opt/cni/bin directory (this was not even created), and the same situation with the /etc/cni/net.d/multus directory.

This was followed by:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep multus
kube-system   kube-multus-ds-khd6k   1/1   Running   0  3m7s

$ cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: macvlan-conf
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
      "type": "macvlan",
      "master": "ens160",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "192.168.1.0/24",
        "rangeStart": "192.168.1.200",
        "rangeEnd": "192.168.1.216",
        "routes": [
          { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "gateway": "192.168.1.1"
      }
    }'
EOF

networkattachmentdefinition.k8s.cni.cncf.io/macvlan-conf created

$ kubectl describe network-attachment-definitions macvlan-conf
Name:         macvlan-conf
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
Kind:         NetworkAttachmentDefinition
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-03-17T18:41:34Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
    Manager:         kubectl-create
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-03-17T18:41:34Z
  Resource Version:  1597
  UID:               29e54d08-70ba-4ad6-8031-f22ad2a73382
Spec:
  Config:  { "cniVersion": "0.3.0", "type": "macvlan", "master": "eth0", "mode": "bridge", "ipam": { "type": "host-local", "subnet": "192.168.1.0/24", "rangeStart": "192.168.1.200", "rangeEnd": "192.168.1.216", "routes": [ { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" } ], "gateway": "192.168.1.1" } }
Events:    <none>

$ cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: samplepod
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: macvlan-conf
spec:
  containers:
  - name: samplepod
    command: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]
    image: alpine
EOF
pod/samplepod created

$ kubectl exec -it samplepod -- ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: eth0@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.6/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I was expecting a "net1" interface also as in the description on the web page:
https://github.com/k8snetworkplumbingwg/multus-cni/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

The cni directories under /opt and /etc were never created.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: Could you provide all your steps? Ive followed this tutorial and everything works normally (tutorial sample pod and your sample pod) How did you create minikube cluster, which driver did you use? Could you provide all your commands?

Comment: @PjoterS I have edited the description and provided all the steps. Since I am a newbie at k8s, I am not sure where the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, it should be ok. Just to confirm, you have machine which runs some virtualization software like (VirtubalBox/VMVare or something esle) and you run RHEL8 using this virtualization application?

Comment: Yes. I am running RHEL on a VmWare workstation as a guest OS on Windows host.

Comment: I tried on normal linux machint, without any additional virtualizaton env. I guess it might need some additional VmWare adjustments.